# Should an endpoint return the records that a user has permissions for or forbidden

Tags: rest, api-design

I have a scenario where my users own the entities they created, but they can have multiple permissions for an entity type, ex.:

- read-my-entity - access to owned entities
- read-all-entity - access to all entities

There are multiple endpoints for diffrent entites like *task*, *request* all with there own set of endpoints and permissions

There is a REST endpoint that can return a collection of these entities and it has an employeeId filter but it's optional

```
GET /entities/?employeeId=X&otherfilters=Y
```

Every user has an EmployeeId in the system.

I see two options how to handle this if the user has read-my-entity permission only and doesn't specify an employeeId:

1. return only the owned entities
2. return HTTP 403 forbidden or something similar and message saying you need specify the employeeId

Somehow the second option seems better to me

I know it's probably an opinionated question, but

1. Is there a best practice how to handle this ?
2. What better options are there ?
3. What are the pros/cons of these approaches  ?

Comment: How about creating this endpoint `/users/{employeeId}/entities` ? returns the entities owned by the user with the given employee id.

Comment: What is _entities_? Is it a resource that can be named? Or _entities_ mean _all stuff that have a relationship with a user_?

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin It's a named resources, like **task**, **request** etc

Comment: @The_Cute_Hedgehog generally I like this approach, but in this case I would need to use a different url depending on the filter

Comment: Hi, I  didn't get what you mean by 'different url depending on the filter'. Filtering, paging and sorting can be part of the resource URI when needed. Could you give us a few examples of your specific filters? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint has an optional field employeeId than you should return its own entities.

Comment: Could you elaborate or give some reference, why ?

Comment: if an api return the data of entities and if this api is authenticated and an employee has entities then you should return its entities nut its request is not authenticated you should not return these data and if user is authenticated and he is authenticated and this api is GET user don't need to provide his id to get his